# stoping django dev server gracefully inside docker container

Tags: python, django, docker

I have `Dockerfile` with django app setup and `docker-compose.yml` with service start up instruction:

```
  backend:
    build: .
    hostname: backend
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

As docker docs recommend I need to use json list CMD format if I want to execute process in current context and being able to stop it gracefully.

But after I run `docker-compose up backend` and after few seconds when server is ready `docker-compose stop` container stops with code 137.

In same setup `gunicorn project.wsgi --workers 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000` works fine.

I also tried to move start up instruction into wrapper script and it **also didn't work**:

```
  backend:
    build: .
    hostname: backend
    command: ["./start.sh"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

start.sh:

```
exec python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I think Django don't have that ability/feature yet

Comment: What is your `ENTRYPOINT`?

Comment: don't have `ENTRYPOINT`

Answer (score 0):

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, set the `stop_signal` to `SIGINT`:

```yaml
backend:
  build: .
  stop_signal: SIGINT
```

Docker sends the SIGTERM signal by default, but Django dev server responds to SIGINT.

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52046161/490592